# What is the difference between `Fixnum` and `3` in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

```
Fixnum.methods.count #=> 99
3.methods.count      #=> 131
```

If they have different methods I would guess they are not exactly the same thing.

1. What is the difference exactly?
2. What's going on under the hood in Ruby?

I'm using *ruby 2.2.1p85 (2015-02-26 revision 49769)*.

Comment: `3` is an instance of `Fixnum`, while `Fixnum` is an instance of `Class`.

Comment: ...and `Class` is an instance of `Class`, and `Class` is an instance of `Class` and...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Aetherus said, `Fixnum` is an instance of a class, so `Fixnum.methods` return all of its class methods, whereas `3.methods` will return `Fixnum` instance methods, since `3` is an instance of `Fixnum`.

For example, basic math operators are instance methods, such as `:+`, `:-`, etc, so `Fixnum.respond_to?(:+)` returns `false`. And `3.respond_to?(:class_variables)` returns `false`, because that method is a class method, so instances of that class does not have access to it.